# How to combine two results from same table

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I'm looking for a way of pulling totals from a transactions table. Sales and return transactions are differentiated by a column, but the value is always stored as a positive.

I've managed to pull the different transaction type totals, grouped by product, as separate rows:

```
SELECT `type`, 
        `product`, 
        sum(`final_price`) AS `value`,
        count(`final_price`) AS `count`
GROUP BY `product`, `type`
```

The result is:

```
Type | Product | Value | Count
S    | 1       | 1000  | 2    
S    | 4       | 750   | 3    
S    | 2       | 300   | 2    
S    | 3       | 10    | 1    
R    | 1       | 500   | 1
```

Ideally, I'd like to have the totals displayed on a single row but in additional columns different columns for ordering purposes. The ideal result would be:

```
Type | Product | s_value | s_count | r_value | r_count
S    | 1       | 1000    | 2       | 500     | 1      
S    | 4       | 750     | 3       | 0       | 0      
S    | 2       | 300     | 2       | 0       | 0     
S    | 3       | 10      | 1       | 0       | 0
```

I've tried `union all` and `left join`s with no joys so far.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: What RDBMS? and are there only the 4 column types with two types?  answer may involve use of PIVOT or use of case statement if number of columns is limited.  If you have an undetermined list of columns, the only way to do this I'm aware of is with Dynamic SQL

Comment: Will `type` contain other values (besides "S" and "R"? Will you need to create a "dynamic" pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions to differentiate by the type of transaction:

```
SELECT   `product`, 
         SUM(CASE `type` WHEN 'S' THEN `final_price` END) AS `s_value`, 
         COUNT(CASE `type` WHEN 'S' THEN `final_price` END) AS `s_count`,
         SUM(CASE `type` WHEN 'R' THEN `final_price` END) AS `r_value`, 
         COUNT(CASE `type` WHEN 'R' THEN `final_price` END) AS `r_count`
GROUP BY `product`, `type`
```

EDIT:
By the forward-quotes around the column names I'm assuming this is a MySQL questions even though it's not explicitly tagged as such.
If this is the case, you can simplify the `count` statements by utilizing MySQL's automatic conversion from Boolean to int which takes `true` as a `1` and `false` as a `0`:

```
SELECT   `product`, 
         SUM(CASE `type` WHEN 'S' THEN `final_price` END) AS `s_value`, 
         SUM(`type` = 'S') AS `s_count`,
         SUM(CASE `type` WHEN 'R' THEN `final_price` END) AS `r_value`, 
         SUM(`type` = 'R') AS `r_count`
GROUP BY `product`, `type`
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thank-you. I followed on by adding in 'total' columns (i.e. sales - refunds) and just needed to add a COALESCE to replace NULL values with a 0.